# XML syntax specification for <! > type tags

Tags: xml

Having pored over the XML W3C Recommendation 1.0, I'm still confused regarding the general nature of the

```
 <!FOO ...>
```

type tags. What is the rationale behind these tags, how are they parsed, and are there any generalizations to this syntax. To me they seem like an almost ad hoc hack added to XML in order to facilitate stuff which wasn't thought of when XML was first designed... Are the valid

```
<! > and <![ ]> (like <!DOCTYPE ...> and <![CDATA []]>)
```

tags hardwired into the XML standard, or can I define my own? If so, how do they get parsed? I'm just asking because I would like to get a complete picture of XML, not because it would be useful ;)

Regards,

Jonas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These kinds of tags[footnote] are hardwired; and pretty much only include comments, `CDATA` and `DOCTYPE`; both of which are holdovers from SGML.

Something similar exists in `<?name ?>` style tags, which *can* be user-defined (with the exception of `<?xml* ?>`, and are called Processing Instructions.

The use of these should be limited (as should the use of `<!` tags; including DOCTYPE and CDATA), if not non-existent (with the obvious exception of comments (`<!--`) and the XML declaration (`<?xml`)).

In certain highly specific applications, of course, Processing Instructions are perfectly legitimate (PHP entry/exit tags (`<?php ?>`) could be considered processing instructions, but PHP isn't PXP, and doesn't obey the rules for where PIs can legally be (hint: you can't have PIs in attributes and inside of tags).

Generally speaking: Don't use processing instructions unless you are planning on preprocessing the XML. Like `CDATA` and `DOCTYPE`, they aren't meant to convey information, but to tell a (pre-)processor how to (pre-)process the XML before/while parsing it.

**Footnote:** `<! >` style instructions aren't actually tags; they are comments, doctypes and CDATA sections. If there is a name for these three constructs together, it escapes me at present.

Comment: Just to pick a nit: they're not "holdovers from SGML", they *are* SGML. HTML and XML are both defined as SGML document types with various restrictions, but there are still SGML tags that live outside of the HTML/XML document that function as processor directives (like how to parse this document, what not to parse at all, and when to pass data through without parsing).

Comment: @Stan Rogers: Well, XML is *essentially* an SGML meta-application, but even so, this point is debatable.

Comment: Anything with `<!` is a declaration. (Except maybe comments?) There are a lot more declarations than just DOCTYPE and CDATA, but they are usually used in the DTD (either external or in the internal subset). The most common that you will see in an internal subset is an ENTITY declaration (including parameter entity declarations/references). You could also see ELEMENT, ATTLIST (attribute), NOTATION , and INCLUDE/IGNORE declarations.

Comment: @DevNull: Well, yes. But let's not get into that. It really is a bit of a hornet's nest. You don't really use it in XML to any great degree, and you certainly don't want to rely on the correct parsing of it all.

Answer (score 1):

`<!…>` sections contain XML-specific processing instructions, and are - in contrast to the general processing instructions `<?…?>` - hardwired into the standard.

If you're interested in where the syntax comes from, you should look into SGML, which is a superset of XML predating it by a decade.